# How can I pass a binary blob from C++ to C#?

Tags: c#-4.0, interop, c++-cli

I'm primarily a C# dev (not much C++ since college), but working on integrating a large collection of existing C++ code into an application. I have a C++/CLI assembly that is buffering the two worlds and have communication from C# through to C++ working fine. The question I have, is that the C++ class has a method call that generates a binary blob (think array of `byte`s in C# world) that I need to get in C# and process (pass around like a solid bag).

What I'm looking for is advice on how to handle the buffer/wrapper method (C++/CLI) between the two worlds. I assumed that I'd pass a `char*` and length, but C# sees that as a `byte*` (I'm assuming that is some C++/CLI "magic").

I also tried passing `array<Byte ^>^` but that haven't had much luck translating the `char*` from the rest of the C++ lib to the `byte` array... and what I have doesn't smell right.

Comment: And what is it that you have?  I haven't done much C++/CLI programming but wouldn't you have to move the contents of the unmanaged char array into a managed byte array?

Comment: that's essentially what I've been attempting to do with little/no success. All the while, wondering if it is the best/right answer.

Comment: It would help if you have shown the code you have that's failing on you.  Just stating that what you have doesn't work and not showing us what you have doesn't really tell us much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a shot at it and came up with this.  Nothing crazy, just allocate the managed array, copy the data and return it.

header:

```cpp
#pragma once
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
namespace CLRLib
{
    public ref class TwiddlerFunctions
    {
    public:
        static array< Byte >^ GetArray();
    };
}
```

implementation:

```cpp
#include "CLRLib.h"
array< Byte >^ CLRLib::TwiddlerFunctions::GetArray()
{
    unsigned char data[] = { 1, 2, 34, 5 };
    // convert the unmanaged array to a managed array
    array< Byte >^ arr = gcnew array< Byte >(sizeof data);
    Marshal::Copy((IntPtr)data, arr, 0, arr->Length);
    return arr;
}
```

C# side:

```cs
using System;
using CLRLib;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte[] arr = TwiddlerFunctions.GetArray();
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", arr)); // 1 2 34 5
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer as it is the approach I'm currently implementing. Thanks, Jeff, for the help. As I move forward, I'll look more at the unmanaged memory stream described by the other respondents.

Answer (score 3):

Have the C++/CLI code hand off a [`System::IO::UnmanagedMemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.unmanagedmemorystream.aspx) to the C# code, which can then use a [`System.IO.BinaryReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx) on said stream to extract data as needed.

As an aside, C++/CLI's `char` is synonymous with C#'s `sbyte`, C++/CLI's `unsigned char` is synonymous with C#'s `byte`, C++/CLI's `wchar_t` is synonymous with C#'s `char`, and C++/CLI's `array<unsigned char>^` is synonymous with C#'s `byte[]`. Note that it's `array<unsigned char>^` or `array<System::Byte>^` rather than `array<unsigned char^>^` or `array<System::Byte^>^`, as `System.Byte` is a value type rather than a ref type.

Comment: Thanks for the tips on the array declarations... that saved me some grief and is well-explained.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an UnmanagedMemoryStream, like so:

```
byte[] message = UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes("Here is some data.");
IntPtr memIntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(message.Length);
byte* memBytePtr = (byte*) memIntPtr.ToPointer();

UnmanagedMemoryStream writeStream = new UnmanagedMemoryStream(memBytePtr, message.Length, message.Length, FileAccess.Write);

writeStream.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
writeStream.Close();
```

The reverse route, roughly:

```
UnmanagedMemoryStream readStream = new UnmanagedMemoryStream(memBytePtr, message.Length, message.Length, FileAccess.Read);

byte[] outMessage = new byte[message.Length];
readStream.Read(outMessage, 0, message.Length);
readStream.Close();

// Convert back into string for this example
string converted = UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetString(outMessage);

Marshal.FreeHGlobal(memIntPtr);
```

I'm sure that MSDN will have more resources

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it appears that this code transfers data (C# -> C++) the opposite direction from what I need (C++ -> C#). Am I missing something?

Comment: Added the reverse steps to the sample